# Run PHP query if previous page == X.com

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, paypal

Really weird situation im unsure of how to fix, Im not a PHP developer so please excuse my naivity.

I've added 4 buy now button to my website, depending on the button, you're redirected to X success page.

On this page I run a query to get records from my table for the session user - I then update my record accordingly.

What is happening though, my users can just visit this page `example.php` and the queries run automatically so I need to somehow say `IF(previous url = Paypal)` then run the queries, if not `die()`

Can anybody advise me as to what the best solution would be?

Comment: Add the last page as a variable inside the session, then read it in next page

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a value of HTTP_REFERER in the superglobal $_SERVER array so you could try something like:

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && preg_match('/paypal/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    // execute queries
}
```

Comment: Note - not all browsers sent the "REFERER" request header so it can't be relied upon.